# Is it possible for a silverlight app to always use the Out of browser app if it is installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

i have a silverlight application (SL3) that is enabled for use out of the browser. what i want to know is, if the user installs the application "out of browser" how do i make my site always launch the out of browser application instead of hosting the silverlight application in the browser... is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't launch the OOB version from your page but you can however remind the user they've installed it already and get them to start the OOB version themselves.

Tim Heuer covers it [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/12/silverlight-out-of-browser-force-install-pattern.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your site can't launch the installed OOB app but you can programatically install it OOB by using Application.Install() which must be called from a user-initiated event (like a button click).